# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in

Tags: php, html

Cannot figure out why I am getting this error?

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in

Here the code:

```
    $con =  mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', '********', '********');
    mysqli_select_db ($con, "id9873966_search") or die mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: `localhost:3306` - try separating the host and port into separate arguments to `mysqli_connect` ~ ie: `$con =  mysqli_connect( 'localhost', '********', '********', 'id9873966_search', 3306 );`

Comment: `mysqli_select_db` also wont be needed, it is the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard port 3306 you should just be able to write

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "id9873966_search");
```

Assuming you actually have a db named id9873966_search

Additionally, if you're on Windows PC you can open CMD as admin and run

```
netstat -a -b
```

This will generate a list of services listening on what ports so you can verify you are in fact using port 3306 on localhost. You can also open "Services" in Windows and ensure that your DB is installed and listening.

It may also be necessary to add a firewall rule on you machine.